# Add percent sign in format command

Tags: tcl

I would like add this sign `%` after my value , I like using `format` command but when I try ,I have this message

> not enough arguments for all format specifiers

What makes sense to me... I know I could use `String concatenation` but I would like to know if there is a solution with this command.

```
set val [format "s%%" "50"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the conversion character in your current format string (`%s`), there are no variables specified and yet you are supplying one. It should be:

```
set val [format "%s%%" "50"]
```